# Chart.js - generateLegend is not a function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Trying to personalize my charts.js legends, I tried the [example](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5070#issuecomment-353575186). My code is the same for the parts about legends.

But I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: myChart.generateLegend is not a function

I use Charts.js 2.9.3 version, installed via `npm install chart.js --save`

My HTML :

```
<div class="canvas">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <div id="myChartLegend"></div>
</div>
```

My JS function :

```
function get_chart($category,$data) {
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myLegendContainer = document.getElementById("myChartLegend");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: $category,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Dépenses (en €)",
          backgroundColor: ["#1D8BDB", "#DB6732","#12DBC4","#DBB007","#2732DB"],
          data: $data
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
            display: false
          },
}});

myLegendContainer.innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();
var legendItems = myLegendContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i += 1) {
legendItems[i].addEventListener("click", legendClickCallback, false);}}
```

**EDIT :**
Here is a CodePen with my code : https://codepen.io/luxarki/pen/GRJLErJ

**FINAL EDIT :**
I declared `var chart = new Chart (x,y)` but called `myChart.generateLegend();`. Corrected to `chart.generateLegend();` and it works.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (Without $data - use simple data). In general `myChart` not declare (You use `chart` as chart.js object. It is like writing "hello.wow()" in your code. Will throw: (TypeError: hello.wow is not a function).

Comment: Hi Ezra, thanks for the help. I changed `myChart.generateLegend();` to `chart.generateLegend();` and it works !